# Adicionar valor em um input conforme seleção de um combobox angular/ionic

Tags: html, ionic, angular

Tenho um input text e preciso de que quando eu escolher uma opção em um combobox receber esse valor, mas sem apagar o que já está escrito.

O que eu tentei:

```
 <ion-textarea name="resposta" #resposta value="{{insercaorapidasistema}}{{respostaautomatica.value}}"
```

Minhas duas tentativas, uma com ngmodel, outra com variável local.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Combo 1</ion-label>
  <ion-select #respostaautomatica>
    <ion-option value="opcao 1 ">Opcao 1</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="opcao 2 ">Opcao 2</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Combo 2</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="insercaorapidasistema">
    <ion-option value="Opcao 1 ">opcao 1</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="Opcao 2 ">opcao 2</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

O problema está em que se eu escrever alguma coisa no input text e depois selecionar um valor da combobox, o que eu escrevo no input some.

Answer (score 0):

Sugiro que você crie um outro campo para incluir o valor total, para que não ocorra uma referência circular. Por exemplo:

```
<div>{{resposta.value}}{{insercaorapidasistema}}{{respostaautomatica.value}}</div>

<ion-textarea name="resposta" #resposta></ion-textarea>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Combo 1</ion-label>
  <ion-select #respostaautomatica>
    <ion-option value="opcao 1 ">Opcao 1</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="opcao 2 ">Opcao 2</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Combo 2</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="insercaorapidasistema">
    <ion-option value="Opcao 1 ">opcao 1</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="Opcao 2 ">opcao 2</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```